# How to use useInfiniteQuery in react High Order Component class?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, higher-order-functions, react-functional-component

Hi I have started working on a project where there are many pages are there. All of the pages shows a list of data on page load. To display the list of data we are using grid (which is MaterialreactTable from material-react-table). Here we have used react High Order Component Concept. The list of data is being displayed as paginated.
Now there is a requirement to change from Paginated view to Infinite Scroll view.
To do so I am trying to implement - useInfiniteQuery. The reference link is here - https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/examples/infinite-scrolling

useInfiniteQuery is basically a hook which cannot be used in class component and meant to use in functional Component.
My question is how to implement useInfiniteQuery in my High Order Component which is a class component ?
Thanks in advance.